# How universal links work when app is installed with no internet connection

Tags: ios, swift4, ios-universal-links

I have started reading about `universal links`,
Although I understood the working but couldn't figure this out on what will happen if the universal link is clicked without having an internet connection.

I saw this behavior in the Twitter app and its opening even without the internet,
But I couldn't understand the process behind the scenes.
Can someone explain this to me

Answer (score 1):

> ... it's opening even without the internet, but I couldn't understand the process behind the scenes.

Once your project is configured to use Universal links, on the first load, the app downloads the rules from `apple-app-site-association` JSON file.

So the OS is able to resolve the clicked universal link without to be connected to the network.